# Datetime from strings adding time and date seperatly

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting to parts of a date time in two string fields I am using the following to convert the date to a datetime which works but how would one add the time element in its in 24 hr format.
You will see the two below mean it was ordered on the 8/12/18 at 0908

Using the following how would I attach the time element of 0808 in 24 hour format so that i get a valid date time result.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
   TrasnactionDate, 
  "ddMMyy", 
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string outp = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

The time element is stored in a variable called TransactionTime of a string.

So the end result would be a valid date time i require.

```
"081218","0908",

"071218","0919",
```

**Edit 2**
Ok I tried adding them as suggested below but I have a null date

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(TrasnactionDate + TransactionTime, "ddMMyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string outp = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
```

Result is 0001/01/01 00:00 when it should be 2018/08/12 09:08

**Edit 3**
I now have the following:

```
 DateTime totalDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(TrasnactionDate, "ddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
DateTime.ParseExact(TransactionTime, "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay; 
string outp = totalDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
```

But I need it in the format

```
yyyyMMdd HH:mm
```

But it is saying when i stuff it in the date time field its invalid. Please someone tell me how is this a invalid value:

20181211 09:08:00

**Edit 4**

To show the field is a valid date time field in sql

[image]

Comment: And what have you already tried? Where do you encounter issues with that?

Comment: Add the time results to the Date results.

Comment: @dymanoid If he knew what to try he wouldn't ask.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly "it" is, which says that?

Comment: @marsze shown in screen shot

Comment: @Dave That is a different question. You should do some research first or open another SO question. But as this is a `datetime` field, you should add the `DateTime` value and not convert it to a string first.

Comment: @Dave: Have a look here: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just concat before parsing?

```
var dateTimeStr = TransactionDate + TransactionTime;
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeStr, "ddMMyyHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Another way:

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(TransactionDate, "ddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
+ TimeSpan.ParseExact(TransactionTime, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

After that, you can output any string format you like:

```
result.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// 20181211 09:08

result.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// 20181211 09:08:00

result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// 2018-12-11 09:08:00
```

Comment: @Dave check your format string. It's not correct. You must use `"ddMMyyHHmm"`

Comment: @marsize i cant its going into sap and it needs it in yyyyddmm

Comment: @Dave you can output any format you like, see my edit.

Comment: var result = DateTime.ParseExact(TrasnactionDate, "ddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
               + TimeSpan.ParseExact(TransactionTime, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DateTime _date =Convert.ToDateTime(result.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm"));

Comment: @Dave `result` already *is* a DateTime. No need to use Convert.

Comment: its working when i debug but when i look in sql field its not saved the value of time even though its a date time.

Answer (score 3):

Try parsing *date part* as `DateTime` but *time part* as `TimeSpan`; then you can add both parts:

```
string TrasnactionDate = "081218";
string TrasnactionTime = "0908";

DateTime dt = 
  DateTime.ParseExact(TrasnactionDate, "ddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
  TimeSpan.ParseExact(TrasnactionTime, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Edit:** Another possibility is

```
// HH - we use 24 hours time representation (see juharr's comment) 
DateTime dt = 
  DateTime.ParseExact(TrasnactionDate, "ddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
  DateTime.ParseExact(TrasnactionTime, "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

**Demo:**

```
var tests = new string[][] {
  new string[] { "081218", "0908"},
  new string[] { "071218", "0919"},
};

DateTime[] result = tests
  .Select(line => new {
    TrasnactionDate = line[0],
    TrasnactionTime = line[1],
  })
  .Select(item => 
     DateTime.ParseExact(item.TrasnactionDate, 
                        "ddMMyy", 
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
     DateTime.ParseExact(item.TrasnactionTime, 
                        "HHmm", 
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay)
  .ToArray();

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(date => $"{date:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
2018/12/08 09:08
2018/12/07 09:19
```

Comment: Since the time part doesn't include AM/PM I'm guessing they need to use the 24 hour format `HH` instead.

Comment: @juharr: no `H` is for `DateTime` when I parse `TrasnactionTime` as a `TimeSpan` (`1908` instead of `0908` will be `19` hours and `8` minutes)

Comment: Yeah, Timespan doesn't know about AM/PM so if the OP needed to handle that then they would have to concatenate instead.